# disable zooming dragging in Google maps by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add codes inside disable() function to disable dragging and zooming in Google maps API v3 by clicking on 'disable' button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var map;

  function initialize() {
var uluru = new google.maps.LatLng(21, 57);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  zoom: 6,
  center: uluru,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});
}


function disable(){

}

</script>


<body onload="initialize()" >

   <input type="button" id="next" value="disableZoomDrag" onclick="disable()">

</body>
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use the [`setOptions()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions) method on the map object:

```
map.setOptions({draggable: false, zoomControl: false, scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true});
```

If this doesn't prevent zooming, you could always set the minimum and maximum zoom to the current zoom level.

There is also the `disableDefaultUI` option, which probably takes all of these events into account, but it might disable clicking on existing elements.

Comment: Just a note, you can also add these when initiating a new instance of the map object: `var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);` where `mapOptions` would be your options: `var mapOptions = {draggable: false, zoomControl: false, scrollwheel: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true};`

Answer (score 9):

@ScottE's answer pointed me in the right direction of using `map.setOptions()`. However, from the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction), I found that there is a more elegant set of options to set. Perhaps these are newer than the answer, but they work pretty well for me.

```
function disablePanningAndScrolling()
{
    map.setOptions({
        zoomControl: false,
        gestureHandling: 'none'
    });
}
```

This completely disables zooming and panning.

To return things to normal, just set the properties back to their defaults:

```
function enablePanningAndScrolling()
{
    map.setOptions({
        zoomControl: true,
        gestureHandling: 'greedy' // or 'cooperative'*
    });
}
```

*: the default is greedy if the page isn't scrollable, cooperative when it is. Pick whichever was the situation in your application.