# disable google maps for selection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i use google map v3 in asp.net application.its working fine.
although what i want is when user selects a particular and presses action button on page i want the map to be disabled for selection.

i tried disabling enclosing div in which map is located but it doesnt work.

here is my code for google maps

for example:

```
<div id="map_canvas" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" 
style="height: 500px; width:   802px;
z-index: 0;">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "disabled for selection" means? Do you want to make it entirely inert? Including any markers or other overlays? What markers and overlays do you have?

Comment: yes i just want to make it disabled so that no action can be performed on it.just like any other controls.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204144/disable-zooming-dragging-in-google-maps-by-clicking-on-a-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using setOptions is not sufficient as in lu1s comment above, I would suggest creating an overlay div to cover up the extents of the map pane, in much the same way that the modal dialog plugins for jquery and such work.  Just show the overlay when you don't want the map to be active. and it will capture any user interactions instead of the map itself.